# Handle ShareActionProvider onClick event

Tags: android, menu, shareactionprovider

How I can get onClick event of a ShareActionProvider menu item?

My application shows some images in a gallery (fragments with imageView) and I need get the onClick event to load the current image from cache, generate a temp file and share it.

My share button:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

I've tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.manage_keywords:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, KeywordActivity.class));
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_item_share:
        /*it should handle share option*/
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And

```
    menuShare = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    menuShare.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any other suggestion??
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Save the image you want to share to the SDCard every time the user click on the ShareActionProvider, full example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.shareactionprovider).getActionProvider();
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getShareIntent());
    shareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider actionProvider, Intent intent) {
            saveImageToSD();
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}




private Intent getShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File sharedFile = new File(sdCard+"/yourPath/yourImage.jpg");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharedFile);

    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    return shareIntent;
}


private void saveImageToSD() {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(getTempFile());
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        bm.recycle();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private File getTempFile() {

    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourPath/");
        directory.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(directory ,"yourImage.jpg");

        try  {
            file.createNewFile();
        }  catch (IOException e) {}

        return file;
    } else  {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed flow is not supported by `ShareActionProvider`. You will need to fork it or come up with some other sharing solution.

Or, better yet, implement a `ContentProvider` that can serve up the image, so you can use a proper `Intent` with `ShareActionProvider` in the first place and not need to change it based upon the user's choice of sharing target. By using your own `ContentProvider`, you can probably avoid the temp file altogether. Depending on where your images are stored, [`FileProvider` may be sufficient for your needs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it, but I would try OnMenuItemClickListener event instead

Comment: it didn't works...  menuShare = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
  menuShare.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    /*should stop here*/
    return false;
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OnShareTargetSelectedListenener of the ShareActionProvider <strike>and then add the picture there to your intent</strike> (you are not allowed to modify your itent here):

```
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItemShare.getActionProvider();
mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider actionProvider, Intent intent) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

So the other solution would be, that you update your intent when you change the current image:

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createIntentForCurrentImage());
```